# Identifying An Unusual Curve (Parametric)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, conic-sections, curves, golden-ratio

**NOTE that: The upper boundary (for positive values of $t$) is defined in terms of infinity, that is at $t=∞$. (There is no lower boundary for negative values of $t$.)**

**NOTE.** To any re-reading this, I was tired when I wrote it and mixed up the equations; now the post should make much more sense!

**Note that the function does not cross $y$ at the top! This upper bound is at $1.618^{3}$. As you can see, it rounds off as it approaches the upper bound!**

See this Graph for further insight:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qqqfuyrhyp

I'm looking for the parametric equations for the curve shown: I already know $y(t)$, it's $y(t)=\frac{1-φ^{-1+t}}{1-φ}+φ^{-1}$; **here** $φ$ is $\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}$. So, all I need is to find $x(t)$, which will also be defined in terms of $φ$.

[image]

Thank you all!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104332/discussion-on-question-by-jinny-ecckle-identifying-an-unusual-curve-parametric).

Answer (score 1):

The given parametric equation for $y(t)$ is incompatible with the graph of the curve. According to the graph, there should exist a real number $T$ such that
$$
y(T)={1-\varphi^T\over1-\varphi}=\varphi^{-3}.
$$
But that implies:
$$
1-\varphi^T=\varphi^{-3}(1-\varphi)=\varphi^{-1},
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
\varphi^T=1-\varphi^{-1},
$$
and that is impossible, because $1-\varphi^{-1}=-\varphi<0$.

The same conclusion can be reached studying function $y(t)$, which is monotonically increasing and has upper bound 
$$
\lim\limits_{t\to+\infty}y(t)={1\over1-\varphi}=\varphi^{-2}<\varphi^{-3}.
$$

EDIT.

With the modified definition $y(t)={1-\varphi^{t-1}\over1-\varphi}+\varphi^{-1}$ one can repeat the above computation for $T$ to find:
$$
\varphi^{T-1}=1+\varphi-\varphi^{-1}=0,
$$
which is possible only in the limit $T\to+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time. I made an error in my statement, it should have been this:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eci0zk3ues

Comment: Sorry, I was very tired when I wrote this and mixed up the equations. The correct equations should make the problem a lot more sensible!

Comment: Even in that case, by repeating my argument above one gets $\varphi^{T-1}=0$, which is impossible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this version of the argument, can you expand it?

Comment: For the correct equation, y seems to be bounded at $1.618^{3}$. What's impossible about bounding x at that y?

Comment: Based on this approximation, you seem to be right:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/suhkikwpl6

I'm still missing why?

If this is the case then the boundary should be the highest possible one, which is apparently less than $1.618^{3}$

Comment: Actually, I think there must be an issue with your argument, please see here!:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qqqfuyrhyp

What do you make of this.

Comment: See my edit: $\varphi^{-3}$ is a limiting value of $y(t)$ for $t\to+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you, but how does this get synthesized with the fact that this graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qqqfuyrhyp Does what I describe at this limit?

Comment: At least it seems to, does it never quite reach the limit? **Note** that this graph shows a good approximation of what I'm looking for at $1.618^{3}$. Only it should curve more gently / look less square.

Comment: It reaches the limit only for $t\to+\infty$, hence you should find a function $x(t)$ defined on $[0,+\infty)$ and vanishing both at $t=0$ and for $t\to+\infty$.

Comment: Something like $x(t)=-t/(1+t^2)$.

Comment: Thank you! This is getting closer! 
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uxp4slp94d

Comment: This: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s4thqylejl Is pretty close. Can you think of something better / closer? If you wouldn't mind? **Note** It's not lower bounded.

Comment: As I wrote above the graph starts at $t=0$. That is unavoidable, because $y(0)=0$.

Comment: Yes; this is most certainly true!! It should start there, as in my fig., however, you should get 'more graph' from minus $t$. Thank you!

Comment: See my update which should explain everything.

Comment: anyhow. now that the question should fully make sense, I'd be very happy to accept your answer if you can find such a function. (Hint: the function will probably be the sum of an infinite series somehow connected to the sum in $y(t)$)